# Format a PGF Plot

Tags: pgfplots

I have a simple PGF plot using this code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}[htpb]
\centerline{
\hbox{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6]
\begin{axis}[enlarge x limits=false, xlabel={$s$}, ylabel={ATA}, grid=major]
\addplot+[mark=square] table[x=x,y=m1]{atak.csv};
\end{axis} \end{tikzpicture}}}
\caption{Test Figure}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

The source is also available [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-ugenZbXWBpZFl6MG9hcmhpNGc/view?usp=sharing) and [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-ugenZbXWBpVVZGbEVmRjE2WFU/view?usp=sharing)

Based on this simple code, I have some questions:

- There exists a lot of distance between the axis title and the axis itself. How can I reduce this space?
- How can I make the axis titles bigger in font size?
- How can increase the plot width without increasing it height?

Answer (score 3):

You can adjust settings in

```
width=15cm,
height=7cm,
xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:0.5)},xshift=0ex,yshift=0.2ex, anchor=center,font=\Large},
ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:0.5)},xshift=0ex,yshift=-3ex, anchor=center,font=\Large}
```

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htpb]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6]
\begin{axis}[width=15cm,height=7cm,enlarge x limits=false, xlabel={$s$}, ylabel={ATA}, grid=major,
       xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:0.5)},xshift=0ex,yshift=0.2ex, anchor=center,font=\Large},
       ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:0.5)},xshift=0ex,yshift=-3ex, anchor=center,font=\Large}]
\addplot+[mark=square] {rand};
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Test Figure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]